# Seconds Counter and score keeper in with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

im a beginner in python and i have a big trouble for this code. im making a small match making game and this game made me hate python.
simply, user should match the photos together and try to do it as fast as possible for getting less time.
however, the timer is never working or giving me recursion limit error.
i want a simple second counter and a way to count the score.
so far, this is what i have and the timer is happening only once. so the label just becoming 1

```
import mycanvas as mc
import tkinter as tk
import random as r
import time



clickedimages=[]
score = 0
seconds=0

def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("550x800")
    root.resizable(0,0)
    coverimg=tk.PhotoImage(file="pics\\qs.png")

    name=""
    images=[]
    coppyimages=[]
    allcanvas=[]
    lbl=tk.Label(root,text="0",font=('robot',20))
    lbl2=tk.Label(root,text=str(score),font=('robot',20))
    lbl.place(x=100,y=750)
    lbl2.place(x=400,y=750)
    #making images
    for x in range(1,11):
        name="pics\\p"+str(x)+".png"
        images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file=name))

        coppyimages.append(tk.PhotoImage(file=name))
        coppyimages.append(tk.PhotoImage(file=name))

    #5x4
    #positioning
    tx=50
    ty=150
    counter=1
    for x in range(0,5):
        for y in range (0,4):
            choice=r.randint(0,len(coppyimages)-1)
            allcanvas.append(mc.myconvas(root,counter,coppyimages.pop(choice),tx,ty,coverimg))
            tx+=120
            counter+=1
        tx=50
        ty+=120

    root.after(1000,timer(lbl))

    root.mainloop()

def timer(lbl):
    global seconds
    seconds+=1
    lbl.configure(text=str(seconds))



def clicked(event):
    if(len(clickedimages)==0):
        event.widget.showorhide()
        clickedimages.append(event.widget)
    elif((len(clickedimages)>0) and (event.widget != clickedimages[0])):
        event.widget.showorhide()
        clickedimages.append(event.widget)
        matchchecker()

def matchchecker():
    global clickedimages,score
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if(clickedimages[0].nameofimage==clickedimages[1].nameofimage):
        print("Its a match")
        clickedimages[0].place_forget()
        clickedimages[1].place_forget()
        score+=1
    else:
        print("wrong :(")
    clickedimages[0].showorhide()
    clickedimages[1].showorhide()
    clickedimages.clear()
    gamechecker()

def gamechecker():
    global  score

    if(score==10):
        print("Game over")





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the class is :

```
import tkinter as tk
import main


class myconvas(tk.Canvas):
    number=0
    myimage=None
    nameofimage=""
    coverimg=None
    show=True
    
    def __init__(self, root,n,img,px,py,dfault):
        super().__init__()
        self["width"] = 100
        self["height"] = 100
        self.number=n
        self.myimage=img
        self.maketheimage(dfault,px,py)
        self.nameofimage = img.cget('file')
        # self.setimagename()
        self.coverimg=dfault;
        self.bind("<Button-1>",main.clicked)
        # root.after(500,self.showorhide())
        
    def maketheimage(self,img,px,py):
        self.create_image(50,50,image=img,anchor='center')
        self.place(x=px,y=py)
    def setimagename(self):
        self.nameofimage=self.myimage.cget('file')
    def showorhide(self):
        if(self.show):
            self.create_image(50,50,image=self.myimage,anchor='center')
            self.show=False
        else:
            self.create_image(50,50,image=self.coverimg,anchor='center')
            self.show=True
```

thank you in advance

Comment: `root.after(1000,timer(lbl))` -> `root.after(1000,timer, lbl)` also avoid the use of `time.sleep` in main thread

Comment: Also, you only call timer once. It will update after 1 second but never again. You need to use .after at the end of the timer function to schedule another call back 1 second later.

Comment: thank you very much. it helped and its working. i have another issue which is about the score. i cannot update the label for score.